# Seo of website created on angularjs (google do not interpolate angularjs expressions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, html, ruby-on-rails-3, seo

I just finished my website : http://www.kiffetescourses.com

This website is made with angularjs and the meta title and description are updated by angularjs like this :

```
title ng-bind="page_title"
meta name="description" content="{{ page_description }}"
```

**I use HTML5 pushstate**

On google webmaster tool, when I explore my website as google, the screenshot returned has content created by angularjs app.

But when I look on google :

https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.kiffetescourses.com

I notice several issues :

1. Title and description do not appear on search result and angularjs expressions appear...
2. Google do not follow links on the home page (in footer)

What I did for ajax SEO :

1. Add meta content="!" name="fragment"

Any idea what I did wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Search engines cannot run javascript so if you're using angularjs to load your contents all the search engine will see is the page with the bindings like that are not rendered.  In order to make this search engine compatible, you need to dish up a version that already have the javascript compiled.  Fortunately, there is a guide for this using node/phantomjs to compile copies of the pages in the backend server for the search engine to read.

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html so, google interprate js